# How can a format an entire row based on if a cell CONTAINS a specific word using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to highlight and entire row if a cell string contains the word "risk". But I need to make it using vba since the person using it will write on it after using the macro.

I have something like:

[image: The client code, the value and a reason:]

The reason will be written afterwards and I need to highlight the row if someone writes the word risk anywhere in this column. Anything can be written there.

I use this to highlite a row when I want a full match:

```
lastReg= Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A1:J" & lastReg)
Rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$J1=""Plat"""

...
```

so I tried:

```
Rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=FIND(""risk"",$J1)>0"
```

But it doesn't work.

Edit: it gives me an execution error so the code itself doesn't run.

Edit2: Someone else uses this macro, and he can't do it by himself so I wanted the code to do it for him.
Also, the code is stored in the personal.xlsb because he runs the code in a different worksheet everyday, so I can't pre config the formatConditions for the worksheet.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not helpful - please elaborate.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do any formatting either.

Comment: And since your vba code is setting up conditional formatting, I don't understand why you can't just use conditional formatting.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it's because I'm not the one who runs the code. It's for a different person in my company who doesn't know how to do it. So I did this macro to help him.

He's been using the macro for a while but he keeps forgeting to format it by himself so I wanted to change it so it would format itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a worksheet change event. place this sub in your worksheet. Whenever any cell in column 5 changes and the value is "risk", it will color the row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Columns(5)

    If Not Intersect(Rng, Target) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "risk" Then
        Target.Offset(, -4).Resize(, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: But it's not a fixed worksheet... 

The person who uses it export it from a plataform he uses and uses a macro to find the clients he needs and then he writes out the reasons, so the macro itself its in the personal.xlsb.

Comment: @DaniMika All you have to do is place this code in what ever worksheet that the person is adding the reasons to.

Comment: But then I would have to do it everyday, right? This person works in a diferent area in my company. He can't use excel much so I did this to help him.
Now he highlights the row by himself, or at least he should. But he keeps forgeting to do it so I wanted to make it a part of the macro itself.

Comment: @DaniMika What I would do is create a blank workbook that the user only has to place on his desktop. When he opens the file it will import the data from the platform. The user then can modify and add the reasons, and as he adds the reasons in column 5, this macro placed in the worksheet will color the row automatically. Then using a button the worksheet can be saved as a new non-macro enabled workbook. By doing this, the blank workbook will not be changed, and can be reused each time he needs to create a new report.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then

        For Each cell In Target.Cells

            With cell

                If UCase(.Value) = "RISK" Then
                    .Font.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Font.Color = vbBlack
                End If

            End With

        Next cell

    End If

End Sub
```